# Bounding restriction of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let us  restrict a (possibly unbounded) random variable $X$ to those events, such that $X\in(2^{n},2^{n+1}]$ and denote this restricted variable with $\tilde{X}$, i.e. $\tilde{X}:=X\cdot I(2^n<X\leq2^{n+1})$, where $I$ denotes the indicator function.

Suppose $X$ satisfies $P(|X|\geq t)\leq Ce^{-ct^2}$, how can I then show that the mean and variance of  $\tilde{X}$ are at most $C'e^{-c'2^{2(n+1)}}$ ?

Comment: What is the value of $\bar X$ when $X>2^{n+1}$ or $X\le 2^n$?  Or did you mean you simply want the _conditional_ probability distribution _given_ that $2^n<X<2^{n+1}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The _mean_ of $\bar X$ is certainly in the interval $(2^n,2^{n+1}]$ if all of the values of $\bar X$ are in that interval. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: ... and the variance of $\bar{X}$ is in the interval $[0,2^{2n-2})$ if all the possible values of $\bar{X}$ are in $(2^n,2^{n+1}]$

Comment: @Henry Can you explain to me how to prove the assertions from your last two comments (I updated my answer to make it more clear how $\tilde{X}$ is defined.

Comment: If $Y$ is restricted to $[0,1]$ then $E[Y] \in [0,1]$ and $Var(Y) \in \left[0,\frac14\right]$, so if $Z$ is restricted to $[a,b]$ then $E[Z] \in [a,b]$ and $Var(Z) \in \left[0,\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}\right]$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=[2^n\leqslant X\leqslant 2^{n+1}]$, then $P(A)\leqslant P(|X|\geqslant2^n)\leqslant C\mathrm e^{-c4^n}$, and $\tilde X\leqslant 2^{n+1}\mathbf 1_A$ hence $E(\tilde X^2)\leqslant 4^{n+1}P(A)$. Now, $x\leqslant\mathrm e^x$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence $x\leqslant(2/c)\mathrm e^{cx/2}$. Applying this to $x=4^n$ yields $$E(\tilde X^2)\leqslant (8C/c)\exp\left(-(c/8)4^{n+1}\right).$$
Finally, $\mathrm{Var}(\tilde X)\leqslant E(\tilde X^2)$ and $E(\tilde X)\leqslant E(\tilde X^2)^{1/2}$ hence the desired controls of the mean and of the variance follow.